# Having issues with attempting to draw the Bode Plot of a complex pole?

Tags: bode-plot, graph

[Here is the graph that I'm trying to achieve.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e86pm4sq840)

\$H(s) = \frac{1}{s^2 + 2s + 100}\$

\$H(s) = \frac{1}{100(\frac{s^2}{100} + \frac{2s}{100} + 1 )}\$

\$\zeta = 1\$ and \$\omega = 100\$ which indicates that if there is a peak, it should occur at \$10^2\$. Instead it occurs at \$10^1\$, what's going on? Also the rules over here http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Bode/BodeReviewRules.html indicate that the frequency would be 0dB until it hits \$\omega_0\$ which is also not the case. It is decreasing at a rate of 20dB/dec before it hits that point. What is going on?

Comment: You can also use Alpha to [factorize your denominator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factors%20of%20s%5E2%2B2s%2B100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$\omega_0 ^2 = 100\$, so \$ \omega_0 = 10\$. Also \$ \zeta = 0.1\$ (1 would be critically damped).